# Firefox: download all file types without prompt

Tags: firefox, download, file-download, mime-types

I am trying to set the default behavior for downloading files in Firefox. Currently it opens a nasty dialog "open with or save", and i can tick a checkbox to perform selected action *for this mimetype* in future.

What I want, is to save files without opening any dialogs **for all, even unknown mimetypes** (just ignoring what the type is). I know there is `browser.altClickSave` option, i need its behavior for simple click. It's ok if the solution will first check mimetype preferences or ignore them.

Please don't tell me to add entries to `mimetypes.rdf` file in profile, this is just a hack. AFAIK it does not allow to set default or wildcard. By the way, it is very unreliable to edit this because i have to do it by hand (Firefox lacks functionality of adding/removing entries in **Settings->Applications** list).

Also please don't discuss security of the mentioned dialog for new types downloads, i basically don't run every file that i download.

If it is not possible to do with bare firefox, any solution with extensions is ok. Using macros is not good because we will waste time on opening dialog and waiting for "ok" button to be active for 3 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this question is more than 2 years old and @krlmlr marked it as a duplicate, i'll answer it myself:

NO, it is not possible to simply download files with firefox.

It is possible however with super extra hassle as described [in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/850152/295090), but it involves too much actions to set up.